Is memory leak cause the system reboot in tomcat9 server?
I find in my application log that indicate memory leak. at a same time my system get reboot is it cause of memory leak.
Application log

16-May-2024 01:00:57.374 WARNING [Thread-4]
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
The web application [admin-api] appears to have started a thread named
[boundedElastic-17] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to
create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.base@11.0.22/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.base@11.0.22/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)  java.base@11.0.22/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
java.base@11.0.22/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1170)
java.base@11.0.22/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
java.base@11.0.22/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
java.base@11.0.22/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
java.base@11.0.22/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
java.base@11.0.22/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Server Log
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-1064-azur Thu May 16 01:01   still running
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-1063-azur Fri May 10 01:03 - 01:00 (5+23:57)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-1061-azur Sun Apr 21 23:22 - 01:03 (18+01:40)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-1060-azur Thu Apr 18 22:19 - 23:22 (3+01:02)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-1060-azur Thu Apr 11 22:18 - 22:19 (7+00:01)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-1059-azur Thu Mar 21 22:14 - 22:18 (21+00:04)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-1058-azur Mon Mar 11 11:27 - 22:14 (10+10:46)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-1058-azur Mon Mar 11 10:12 - 11:27  (01:14)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-1058-azur Fri Mar  8 22:00 - 10:12 (2+12:12)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-1057-azur Wed Mar  6 09:47 - 22:00 (2+12:12)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-1057-azur Fri Mar  1 08:38 - 09:47 (5+01:09)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-1057-azur Wed Feb 28 21:35 - 18:23  (20:47)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-1057-azur Wed Feb 28 15:15 - 21:35  (06:20)

I want to know is it causes to system reboot or how to solved it.

No. This is a warning appearing during shutdown, it isn't the actual cause of the shutdown.

It is impossible to know that with the information provided.

from my experience, you don't need to worry about it, here is a warning message I see in my service from time to time, which is caused by shutdown

appears to have started a thread named
[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[Token->2z6y3yb316jld2ozk5ui8|6ed8bcb0]-HelperThread-#2]
but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory
leak.


some other references:
Svetlin Zarev has told nothing to worry about. It is the standard message of tomcat. He has given root cause analysis like below:
This problem is occurred when an application has started ScheduledExecutor (but this will happen with any other Thread/TheadPool) and didn't shut it down on contextDestroyed. So check if you are shutting down your threads on application/server stop.

Resource Link: Tomcat8 memory leak
